# Drilldown in Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have drill-down facility in Jquery datatable?

For example, I want to show the output like below.

Organization          Code

+Org1                     O1

on expanding of Org1,

It should display,

-Org1

+Department1        D1

When we expand Department1,

it should display

+EmployeeName1     Emp1

like this....

Any other solutions apart from Jquery datatable like gridview will also be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this requirement is not a good one. Very hard to implement. Try not to design your UI in this way.  If you insist, my suggestion is: do the collapse/expand operations in a "div", but not to one of the "tr" element.  ( I mean, collapse/expland operation won't change the table's row number)

e.g:

collapse status:

```
row1:   +Org1
row2:   +Org2
row3:   +Org3
```

expanded status:

```
row1:   -Org1
          +Department1
row2:   +Org2
          -Department2
            +Employee2.1
            +Employee2.2
row3:   +Org3
```

Further tips you should know, dataTable gives us 3 most important features:

- pagination
- filtering
- ordering

If you collapse & expand a row, you will get problems about: how to re-paginate, how to re-draw your table, and how to rearrange the table's layout?

As far as I know,  "dataTable" is easy to get start, but hard to get further, especially when you want to add some your own new features, you have to modify its source code (and 15 minutes later, you will give up...)

Because, dataTable based on :

1. your table's structure should be very clear and easy, you shoud not collapse any row or column.
2. in the target table, there's no complicated javascript logic, especially those which may change your table's layout.

Finally, maybe this page will give you an idea about what you want: http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/collapsibleGroups.html